React createElement event handler not being passed when using component as type
When I use createElement, I'm able to pass a onClick event handler inside the props argument when using a string as the type argument (built-in HTML tag) and it works. However, if I use a component as the type argument, it does not works. How can I make it work?
import { createElement } from 'react'

const InnerComponent = () => {
  return createElement(
    'button',
    null,
    'Click me (does not work)'
  )
}

const Component = ({ children }) => {
  const handleClick = () => { console.log('onClick!') };

  let props = {
    onClick: handleClick,
  };
 
  return createElement(
    InnerComponent,
    props,
    children,
  )
}

export default Component

Here is a demo.
Thank you.

Looks like you are passing the prop to the InnerComponent but not actually using it.
const InnerComponent = ({ onClick }) => {
  return createElement(
    'button',
    { onClick },
    'Click me works now'
  )
}


Oh no! It's been a while without using React. Thanks.
